# Limit of $(1-c^n)^{bn}$ when $n\to\infty$, for $c \in (0,1)$ and b is positive constant (arbitrary large).

Tags: limits

Limit of $(1-c^n)^{bn}$ when $n\to\infty$. For $c \in (0,1)$ and b is positive constant (arbitrary large).

The inner part grows to 1 exponentially. The outer part, however, decreases the whole value exponentially.

I tried some Matlab simulations, they all converge to 1.
I wonder how to justify the result through mathematical proof.

In addition, is it possible to characterize the convergence speed? Linear (exponential), sublinear, etc.?

Comment: Limit when what variable tends to where?

Comment: Thanks, @jjagmath, I edited the post, it's when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Take the logarithm  and use $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR, you answered my question!

Comment: @MartinR Do you think it is possible to characterize the convergence speed?

Answer (score 2):

I will show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \log((1-c^n)^{bn})=0$ , the conclusion follows easily.

$$\log((1-c^n)^{bn}) = bn \log(1-c^n) = bn(-c^n) \cdot \frac{\log(1-c^n)}{-c^n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}\to 0\cdot 1 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! You are correct.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to characterize the convergence speed?

Comment: Let $a_n$ be your sequence, then $\log a_n \approx -bnc^n$, therefore, $a_n-1 \approx e^{-bnc^n}-1 \approx -bnc^n$